# Photo name field always null

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form to edit a few fields in the db and I have one field to upload a photo. All text fields are updated in the db except the image field, photo name always null and I don't know why! This parameter is always null: $profile_img. Anyone can help me out. I am using CodeIgniter. Thanks
This is My Controller:

```
function superadmin_landing_content_edit() {

        $content_id = $this->uri->segment(4);

        if (empty($_FILES['content_img']['name']))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('content_img', 'Image', 'required');
        }

        if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
        {
            if(isset($_FILES["content_img"]["name"]) and !empty($_FILES["content_img"]["name"])) {

                $config['upload_path'] = $this->config->config["public_path"]."landing/";
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '20000000';
                $config['max_width'] = '2024';
                $config['max_height'] = '2024';
                $this->load->library('upload');

                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                $result = $this->upload->do_upload('content_img');
                if($result>=1) {
                $imageinfo = $this->upload->data();
                $profile_img = $imageinfo["file_name"];
                $profile_img = $profile_img."*".'/var/www/html/upload/home/landing/'.$profile_img; //always null
            }

        }
            $data = array(
                'name'                  => $this->input->post('name'),
                'image_link'            => $profile_img, //here always null
                'type'              => $this->input->post('type'),
                'link'              => $this->input->post('link'),
                'property_type_id'      => $this->input->post('prop_id'),
                'orientation_id'        => $this->input->post('ori_id'),
                'state_id'          => $this->input->post('state'),
                'city_id'           => $this->input->post('city'),
                'flag'              => $this->input->post('flag'),


            );


            if ($this->form_validation->run() === true)
            {
                $this->Admin_model->update_landing_content($content_id, $data);


            }
        }


        $this->load->view('admin/superadmin_landing_content_edit', $data);
}
```

And here is My View:

```
<?php $content_id = $content['id']; ?>
<?php $attributes = array("name" => "content_img_edit", "id" => "content_img_edit", "class" => "edit_view","method" => "post");
echo form_open_multipart("admin/admin/superadmin_landing_content_edit/".$content_id, $attributes); ?>      

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Image</label>
    <?php echo form_upload(array("id"=>"content_img", "name"=>"content_img", "class"=>"form-control"))?>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit', 'class="btn btn-default"');?>
    <input type="button" name="btnBack" class="btn btn-default" id="btnBack" value="Landing Content List" onclick="window.location.href='<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/admin/superadmin_landing_content_list'" />
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Please cut away all the code that is irrelevant for your problem.

Comment: I edited my code..

Comment: what are you getting in  $imageinfo? also  $this->load->library('upload'); is there?

Comment: Yes $this->load->library('upload') is already in my code. $imageinfo is NULL

Comment: can your refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162048/codeigniter-image-file-cannot-be-upload/46171488#46171488

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
   $result = $this->upload->do_upload('content_img');
    if($result>=1) {
```

With

```
  if (!$this->upload->do_upload('content_img')){
    $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
    } else {
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try like this one:

Controller:

if(!empty($_FILES['content_image']['name']))
        {
          // file upload code start
          $config['upload_path'] ='./uploads/'; //file or image upload folder
          $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
          $this->load->library('upload', $config);
          $this->upload->initialize($config);
          if (!$this->upload->do_upload('content_image'))
          {
            echo  $this->upload->display_errors();
            return false;
          }
          else
          {
              $upload_data = $this->upload->data('content_image');
              $content_image = $upload_data['file_name'];
              $data = array('content_image'=>$content_image,
                );
              //$this->db->where('id',$id)->update('student',$data);
          }
        }
```